# Save SPSS data to existing worksheet (replace) in Excel creates new worksheet

Tags: excel, odbc, spss

I have an Excel file that auto-computes some summary statistics for data from a tab and my objective is to export SPSS data exactly to that tab.

I am using an older version of SPSS and I found this syntax on another post that sort of addressed my need

```
SAVE TRANSLATE /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=<Path>;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;'
  /ENCRYPTED
  /MISSING=IGNORE
  /REPLACE
  /TABLE='Data'
  /KEEP=<VARS>.
```

The complication is that up until last week, this was working like a chart, but now all of a sudden this same syntax, when used with the same files I tested before, always creates a new tab called "Data1" instead of replacing the existing tab "Data"

Would anyone have a clue why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: In case anyone else is facing the same issue - I was able to come up with a workaround - apparently, when I exported from SPSS, it seemed to create a named range in my Excel file called "Data" - I don't know if it was because this conflicted with the existing worksheet named "Data" and hence it created "Data1" but the fix that worked for me was I myself defined a named range called "Data" covering the complete sheet named "Data" and saved the template and then ran the SPSS code - and this exported my SPSS data exactly to 'Data' sheet as expected.